# Why is FileInputStream is used for reading config.properties rather than FileReader

Tags: java, properties-file

InputStream (FileInputStream to be specific) is meant to read binary data such as audio files but why FileInputStream is used in Java for reading config.properties file which basically is a collection of Key-Value pairs(Sring values). Why should we not use Reader(FileReader)

Comment: Can you point out place in Java source code which it is used?

Comment: Your question is unclear. 1. You *can* [use a `Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)). 2. You seem to asking us why some unknowm programmer didn't use it in some unknown piece of code. You're asking the wrong people, in the wrong place.

Comment: @EJP - I wanted to set a properties file with URL , login details and other commonly used stuff. When I looked at different Java tutorial sites, I see them using FIleInputStrea, for reading and writing properties and none of them are binary data sepcific. So I just wanted to ask this in this forum to make myself clear. FYI, elsewhere I didn't post this question

Comment: So you are now askng us about unknown Java tutorial sites and the Unknown programmers who wrote them. Same problem. Pointless question.